# Visual Studio Lightswitch Auto Fill for existing data

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-lightswitch, autofill

I am new to using visual studio lightswitch and I have formed a table with data, but I want to know if there's a way I can get it so that when I start typing, suggestions will come up. As a lot of the data (i.e. Company Name) is repeated throughout, so it would save me typing it out in full every time. I don't want to use a drop box as it cant be limited. I have got this far without typing code so if we could keep it basic that would be great. Thanks

I am really desperate; Any help or comments would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

LS HTML 2013 supports filtering/searching collections out of the box, just mark all searchable fields of your entities as "Is Searchable" and display the filter/search box on your screen, e.g. having your Customers displayed on a BrowseCustomers screen, you can trigger this capability as following:

```
myapp.BrowseCustomers.created = function (screen) {
    screen.Customers.showSearch();
};
```

if you need "more control", you can add a dataitem to the screen (e.g. string "FilterTerm"), bind it to the query and tweak the LS createQuery method for your specific needs (e.g. the Customers VisualCollection), a good example can be found at [Progressive insight on autocomplete as you type in the Lightswitch html Client](http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=1670)